# Remove appmenu -- Need my menus back

Tags: ubuntu-mate, appmenu

I am trying to remove appmenu because it has eliminated the text menus for many programs.

appmenu removes the menu from applications and adds it the panel via a plugin.

If you don't have the panel plugin added to the panel, you'll need to remove this module.

I tried this.

```
andy@7_~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove appmenu-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'appmenu-gtk' can't be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

This search is only a partial listing.

```
apt search appmenu
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
appmenu-gtk-module-common/bionic,bionic,now 0.6.94-1 all [installed,automatic]
  Common files for GtkMenuShell D-Bus exporter

appmenu-gtk2-module/bionic,now 0.6.94-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  GtkMenuShell D-Bus exporter (GTK+2.0)

appmenu-gtk3-module/bionic,now 0.6.94-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  GtkMenuShell D-Bus exporter (GTK+3.0)

appmenu-qt/bionic 0.2.7+14.04.20140305-0ubuntu2 amd64
  application menu for Qt
```

Uninstall the MATE applet app menu and the vala panel appmenu and restart.